# How to map mongodb data to neo4j

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

The project I am working on is planning to implement a new feature that is recommending products to the users(which are sellers in our case) based on their search and the stock they have. Currently, we are using MongoDB as database. To make the predictions we need to import data from MongoDB to neo4j with relationships. For mapping relationships, I referred to the following site https://medium.com/neo4j/transform-mongodb-collections-automagically-into-graphs-9ea085d6e3ef and I was able to map relationships within a document but I was not able to map relationships among the table. Is there a proper way to import data from MongoDB to neo4j DB with relationships mapping?